# Auto layout of right-aligned view not working

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to adapt this tableview section header view to auto layout so it will adapt for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus. This is the desired result
[image: desired result]

which has 3 views named `stringView`, `favoriteCount` and `heartImage`. The following screenshots will have a grey background set on each view to make it easier to see what is going on.

What I don't understand is that the following

```
@"|-(15.0)-[stringView]-(>=20.0)-[favoriteCount(44.0)]-[heartImage(22.0)]-(10.0)-|"
```

produces
[image: example 1]

with the count and heart views nowhere to be seen. So it feels as if the containing view is far wider than it needs to be, but I'm not aware that I have any control over that as the returned view from this method should automatically be sized to the tableview width shouldn't it?

BTW This is all happening inside the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` method which looks like

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section == 0) {
        // My Favourites menu
        UIView *myFavoritesMenuView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [myFavoritesMenuView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2 alpha:1.0]];

        UILabel *stringView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [stringView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [stringView setText:@"My Favourites"];
        [stringView setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [stringView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:16.0]];
        [stringView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [myFavoritesMenuView addSubview:stringView];

        NSDictionary *favoriteArticles = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"FavoriteArticles"];
        UILabel *favoriteCount = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [favoriteCount setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [favoriteCount setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:16.0]];
        [favoriteCount setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [favoriteCount setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
        [favoriteCount setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [myFavoritesMenuView addSubview:favoriteCount];

        if (favoriteArticles && favoriteArticles.count > 0) {
            [favoriteCount setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)favoriteArticles.count]];
        } else {
            [favoriteCount setText:@""];
        }

        UIImageView *heartImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart-button-on"]];
        [heartImage setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [heartImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [myFavoritesMenuView addSubview:heartImage];

        // Create the views dictionary
        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(stringView, favoriteCount, heartImage);

        // Horizontal layout - note the options for aligning the vertical center of all views
        NSString *horizontalFormat = @"|-(15.0)-[stringView]-(>=20.0)-[favoriteCount(44.0)]-[heartImage(22.0)]-(10.0)-|";

        [myFavoritesMenuView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:horizontalFormat
                                                                                    options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                                      views:views]];

        // Vertical layout - we only need one "column" of information because of the alignment options used when creating the horizontal layout
        NSString *verticalFormat = @"V:|-[stringView]-|";
        [myFavoritesMenuView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:verticalFormat
                                                                                    options:0
                                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                                      views:views]];

        return myFavoritesMenuView;
    }

    // handle other section headers here
}
```

Incidentally, I've also tried this by creating a UIView as separate xib, containing just the text label aligned left and heart image aligned to trailing edge of superview and am seeing exactly the same issue with the heart not visible (presumably off screen to the right).

Comment: Is the header view being created in code? Make sure you call [myHeaderView setTranslatesAutoresizingMasksIntoConstraints:NO].

Comment: Show the entire code you have in tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: so we can see how you're creating this view. The constraints you show should work ok (assuming that you also have the correct vertical constraints).

Comment: @MikeTaverne Yes the header view is being created in code. If I call [myFavoritesMenuView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]; then this container view doesn't even appear in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of the entire table view is incorrect (the table view is square for some reason rather than fitting to the screen) so the missing subviews are off screen to the right. Discovered it when I changed to run in iPhone 6 in landscape view and the subviews appeared...

Comment: Did you set the constraints of the table view? If yes, can you show us them?

Comment: It turns out that I hadn't manually set constraints on the table view in the storyboard and it was using whatever size it was set to. Since the table view DOES resize in the storyboard editor when you change the viewing width and height, it seems inconsistent that sensible constraints aren't added (matching it to the superview size) rather than setting it to the current size.

Comment: 1) What do you mean exactly by "change the viewing width and height": which viewing? 2) Are "Use Size Classes" and "Use Auto Layout" checked or unchecked in the storyboard settings?

Comment: Both "Use Size Classes" and "Use Auto Layout" are enabled on the storyboard. I mean the X/Y/Width/Height fields that set the Frame of the tableview. So if I have the storyboard view set to Any/Any, but don't have any constraints set on the tableview and make it fill the available area, then when I run the app in iPhone 5S, the tableview is actually set to be 600pt width, not have its edges set to the superview. So basically it is absolutely necessary to set constraints.

Comment: Yes, it is absolute necessary.